# How to force redraw stateless widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

My code is as follows:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  var providers = [EmailAuthProvider()];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null) { // content depends on external variable
      return SignInScreen(
        providers: providers,
      );
    } else {
      return ProfileScreen(
        providers: providers,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the widget doesn't redraw itself following the actions: it still shows SignInScreen instead of ProfileScreen after signing in.

I can wrap it by stateful widget and force redraw with `setState()`.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var providers = [EmailAuthProvider()];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null) {
      return SignInScreen(
        providers: providers,
        actions: [
          AuthStateChangeAction<SignedIn>((context, state) {
            setState(() {});
          }),
          AuthStateChangeAction<UserCreated>((context, state) {
            setState(() {});
          }),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return ProfileScreen(
        providers: providers,
        actions: [
          SignedOutAction((context) {
            setState(() {});
          }),
        ],
      );
    }
  }
}
```

But is there a simple way?

And I would avoid using `go_route` methods because I don't need routing in my application. And I would like to add `signIn` widget there in simple way.

Comment: The use of `StatefulWidget` is to change the state, so  There's  no need to force `StatelessWidget` to redraw.

Comment: @saad I would like the widget to rebuild after signing in (to replace SignInScreen by ProfileScreen) - pls see the edited question

Comment: you can check the answer thats the right way to do it

Comment: You should always add @immutable to your widgets (stateless or stateful) and ensure compliance, including making all your widget variables final.  If you need to update something, it *should* be in the State of a Stateful widget.